# How Stack Overflow supports solutions that helps developers to use Stack Overflow in their website development solutions?

Tags: discussion, design

I would like to add my solution to the list of solutions that enable users to use Stack Overflow in their website, something like [stackTack](https://stackapps.com/questions/518/stacktack-a-javascript-widget-you-can-stick-anywhere).

Does providing such solutions complies with the Stack Overflow policy (I believe yes)?

How does Stack Overflow supports those development solutions?

Do they have a forum for discussing those issues (I did not find it), or Stack Overflow does not gives any support for discussing or displaying solutions for helping users use Stack Overflow?

Comment: you need to wait until you reach this reputation (it is usualy quick);